# Text (computer written) recognition with python?

Tags: python, object-detection, text-recognition

I have images that aren't timestamped and I need to rename and timestamp them for a project.

Here's an example of the timestamp, written at the top of every image:

[image]

So the question is, is there a way I can *translate (detect)* each number on the timestamp in the image shown? Perhaps I could use `cv2` or `tensorflow` to do this?

Also I was thinking even training a decision tree if I were to crop each digit and create a series of same *sized 1 channel arrays* to train on.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a simple OCR algorithm?
The numbers and letters in the image is very clear, which I think an OCR algorithm will work fine.

A simple test with https://ocr.space/ produces the following:

```
****** Result for Image/Page 1 ******
14042018 Ph.n
```

For sure, training a model will be helpful if you have the corresponding labels.

Comment: Absolutely awesome! Thanks for that, I didn't know OCR existed :)

Answer (score 1):

When you only have computer-written text, you might want to test [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) for OCR.